Understanding Circular/Spiral motion in uniform magnetic field
We know that kinetic energy is preserved in the case where the velocity of the charged particle is directly perpendicular to the magnetic field. The analysis of the force that the particle exhibits circular motion. However, it's not immediately intuitive why this is the case and why no energy is injected into the charge.
We could consider some physical setup in this case which doesn't inject energy into the particle. However, the magnets will probably repel/move until the configuration doesn't work. Since we need energy to maintain such a system, how could we be sure that the magnetic field does not impart any energy on the charge? Or is this line of reasoning wrong?
In addition, why does slight deviations in the angle between velocity/magnetic field lead to continuous losses/gain in energy?

Magnetic fields cannot do work on charged particles. Rate of doing work is $\vec{F}\cdot \vec{v}$ and the Lorentz force due to the magnetic field is always perpendicular to the velocity.
Charged particles lose energy when moving in magnetic fields because they accelerate and emit electromagnetic radiation.
